# How to fill in a field based on conditional subsetting from 2 other fields

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

I have a data frame that looks something like this

```
vessday  gearval  gear  otherfields
152      1        OTB   a
152      0        NA    b
152      1        OTB   c
152      1        HMD   b
152      0        NA    e
153      1        OTT   f
153      1        OTT   g
153      0        NA    h
```

I want to add a field to my data frame, `gearkey`, and fill it with the most frequent `gear` for each `vessday`, not counting NAs (so, when `gearval==1`). `otherfields` is there as an indication that the data has loads of other fields, and there are not duplicate lines.

I want my data frame to look like below, except the real one has 2.5 million records and a few thousand unique `vessday`s.

```
vessday  gearval  gear  otherfields  gearkey
152      1        OTB   a            OTB   
152      0        NA    b            OTB   
152      1        OTB   c            OTB   
152      1        HMD   b            OTB   
152      0        NA    e            OTB   
153      1        OTT   f            OTT   
153      1        OTT   g            OTT
153      0        NA    h            OTT
```

The closest I think I got was this

```
data$gearkey[unique(data$vessday) & data$gearval==1] <- mode(data$gear)
```

But I get the error

> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Now, my brain has turned into mushy peas and I have no idea how to do this... Any help would be much appreciated!

## **Update**

I might have accepted @akrun's answer a bit too soon: his `base R` line produces the desired output, but takes 2+ hours for each of my datasets (of which I have several). So, no good.

After getting rid of the times class on my data, I tried the `dplyr` block and although it seems to produce the right result, I can't have `mutate` to update my data with the new column (still don't know why).

So, ended up trying a different route, and this works (in less than 10 mins per file) and doesn't seem to bother with the times class:

```
library(data.table)

Mode <- function(x, na.rm=T) {
        if(na.rm){
            x = x[!is.na(x)]
        }
        ux <- unique(x)
        ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
    }

df1 <- data.table(df1)
df1[, `:=`(newgear=Mode(gear), by="vessday"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
library(dplyr)

Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
 } 

df1 %>% 
    group_by(vessday) %>% 
    mutate(gearkey= Mode(gear))

#    vessday gearval gear otherfields gearkey
#1     152       1  OTB           a     OTB
#2     152       0   NA           b     OTB
#3     152       1  OTB           c     OTB
#4     152       1  HMD           b     OTB
#5     152       0   NA           e     OTB
#6     153       1  OTT           f     OTT
#7     153       1  OTT           g     OTT
#8     153       0   NA           h     OTT
```

Or using `base R`

```
df1$gearkey <-  with(df1, ave(gear, vessday, FUN=function(x) Mode(x)))
df1$gearkey
#[1] "OTB" "OTB" "OTB" "OTB" "OTB" "OTT" "OTT" "OTT"
```

#### Update

Modified version of `Mode` by @Catarina Aires

```
  Mode <- function(x, na.rm = T) { 
            if(na.rm){
               x = x[!is.na(x)] }
          ux <- unique(x)
          ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))] }
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(vessday = c(152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 153L, 
153L, 153L), gearval = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), gear = c("OTB", 
NA, "OTB", "HMD", NA, "OTT", "OTT", NA), otherfields = c("a", 
"b", "c", "b", "e", "f", "g", "h")), .Names = c("vessday", "gearval", 
"gear", "otherfields"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. Would love to try your suggestion, but cannot install the dplyr package: it says the "dependency 'BH' is not available for package". Will have to sort that first.

Comment: @CatarianAires You can do this in base R. I thought with a large dataset it would be easier with dplyr or data.table. The same code in `base R` would be `df1$gearkey <- with(df1, ave(gear, vessday, FUN=function(x) Mode(x)))`

Comment: Managed to install BH and dplyr, but one of my `otherfields` is a time, and the `times` type appears not to be supported.

Comment: I have tried you other suggestion, but it just copied the `gear` column to the `gearkey`. I really have to look at this with fresh eyes tomorrow, but you have given me food for thought! Many thanks!

Comment: @CatarinaAires  If it is not supported, can you try the `ave` code.  The `ave` worked based on the data in my post.  Can you check it with the example data

Comment: I have, but this has copied the `gear` column exactly as it is, not choosing the most frequent value and filling it for all records in each `vessaday`

Comment: @CatarinaAires  Not sure about the problem.  The `gear` column was 'character' class in my data

Comment: The problem with your suggestion was that it wasn't excluding the NAs from the mode - it wasn't copying the gear column either, I just happened to be looking at a particular day when the mode was NA. This little change to the `Mode` function did the trick: `Mode <- function(x, na.rm = T) {
    if(na.rm){
        x = x[!is.na(x)]
    }
    ux <- unique(x)
    ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}` Many thanks!

Comment: @CatarinaAires  Thanks for the comment. I just wonder how I got the correct result even with `gear` having NAs though